# Creating Docx, PDF, XSL-FO

Tags: java, xml, xslt, pdf, ms-office

[Background Info]

We had a solution in place to use Word automation serverside to convert HTM documents into Docx, PDF or Print documents. This solution broke in the latest version of Windows Server 2012. We learned that MS does not intend on Word working in this manner and after trouble shooting with MS support Engineers we have come to the conclusion that it will never work.

[Currently]

I am currently researching potential technologies and tools that my company can use to regain this functionality. We need to be able to create Docx, PDF and print files to a local printer.

I have looked into a number of tool already and I am currently leaning towards Apache FOP this seems to handle PDF and Printing for us.

However, I'm looking for some advice and suggested tools that we could use to implement a pure Java approach. Currently our application creates HTM files with all the required information. So ideally we would like to take these HTM files and "Convert" them into Docx/XLS-FO format.

[Question]

So my question that I'm hoping you will be able to help me with.
What is the best tools that I can use to get from

1. HTM to Docx
2. HTM to PDF

Or what would be the best process for achieving this? has anyone had success finding a solution for this in the past?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the level of control and the complexity of the source HTML. There are [HTML to FO stylesheets](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-xslfo2app/) but you might find them wanting for your specific need.

So you could use the [Jericho](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html) parser to read the HTML and generate FO. Or you generate the target format directly using Apache PDFBox and [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/)

It all boils down to the level of control you want/need

Answer (score 0):

[docx4j-ImportXHTML](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j-ImportXHTML) will get you from XHTML to docx.  From there, you can use docx4j (or some other solution eg LibreOffice/OpenOffice) to do docx to PDF.

docx4j supports docx to XSL FO, and by default uses FOP.